# No Definition for GetQueryNameValuePairs in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

All,
I'm working on my first Azure Function.  The intent of the function is to take in text and spell check it using the Bing cognitive API.  However, I am unable to compile because at the string text = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()... line in my code because it states HTTPRequestMessage does not contain a definition for 'GetQueryNameValuePairs' and no extension method 'GetQueryNameValuePairs' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpellCheck.Functions
{
    public static class SpellCheck
    {
        [FunctionName("SpellCheck")]
        //public async static Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            //values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", text));

            //error here
            string text = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "text", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            text = text ?? data?.text;

            // Replace the accessKey string value with your valid access key. - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1221350/Getting-Started-with-the-Bing-Search-APIs
            const string accessKey = "MY_ACCESS_KEY_GOES_HERE";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", accessKey);

            //  The endpoint URI.
            const string uriBase = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?";
            const string uriMktAndMode = "mkt=en-US&mode=proof&";

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            string uri = uriBase + uriMktAndMode;

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", text));

            using (FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

           string client_id;
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-MSEdge-ClientID", out IEnumerable<string> header_values))
            {
                client_id = header_values.First();
            }

            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return text == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass text on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Text to Spell: " + text);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have created an Azure Function v2(.Net Core). There's no such method `GetQueryNameValuePairs` on `HttpRequestMessage` in .Net Core/Standard assembly, it's available in .Net Framework.

The quick fix would be create a v1(.NetFramework) Function Project. If you want to stay with v2 function, code refactor is necessary.

In a v2 Httptrigger template, you can see `HttpRequest req`(in your grey comment) and it uses `req.Query["name"]` to get query parameter. There're several other changes necessary as we changed `HttpRequestMessage` to `HttpRequest`. Besides, `TraceWriter` in v1 is also abandoned, in v2 we use `ILogger`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the refactor a shot.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have query parameters: *firstname* and *lastname*, then you could try this:

```
    var qs = req.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

    string firstName = qs.Get("firstname");
    string lastName = qs.Get("lastname");
```

Comment: Was looking a lot for this simple and yet effective solution, thanks!